# Is there any way to return 2 values from a single function in Firebase cloud functions and store them in a different node in database?

Tags: android, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

So this is how I add child nodes and assign values to them in firebase realtime database using firebase cloud functions.

```
export const addUserInfo = functions.database
    .ref('/Users/{UserID}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        const userData = snapshot.val()
        const username = userData.username
        const userUID = context.params.UserID 

        console.log(`${username} has UID ${userUID}.`)

        return snapshot.ref.parent!.parent!.child('userInfo').child(`${userUID}`).set({ "username": newUsername, "uid": userUID})
    })
```

I have another similar function:

```
export const addUserToWhitelist = functions.database
    .ref('/Users/{UserID}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        const userData = snapshot.val()
        const username = userData.username

        console.log(`${username} has been whitelisted`)

        return snapshot.ref.parent!.parent!.child('whitelist').set({ "username": newUsername})
    })
```

So basically I am adding user information to two different locations in Firebase database using two unique functions.

*You cannot have more than 1 return statement in a single cloud function.*

So is there any way I can add both the information data in their respective unique locations in firebase database using a single fucntion? I mean include the return statement of second function can be executed in first one itself? This will significantly help in reducing size of code and also help in saving the function invocation to an extent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write the data to two locations in a single Cloud Function, you can use `Promise.all` to wait for both writes to be completed.

Something like:

```
export const addUserToWhitelist = functions.database
    .ref('/Users/{UserID}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        const userData = snapshot.val()
        const username = userData.username

        console.log(`${username} has been whitelisted`)

        const parent = snapshot.ref.parent!.parent!

        return Promise.all([ 
            parent.child('userInfo').child(userUID).set({ "username": newUsername, "uid": userUID}),
            parent.child('whitelist').set({ "username": newUsername})
        ]);
    })
```

---

Alternatively, you could perform both updates in a single write operation to the database, by wrapping them into a single multi-location update:

```
export const addUserToWhitelist = functions.database
    .ref('/Users/{UserID}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        const userData = snapshot.val()
        const username = userData.username

        console.log(`${username} has been whitelisted`)

        let updates = {};
        updates[`userInfo/${userUID}`] = { "username": newUsername, "uid": userUID};
        updates['whitelist'] = { "username": newUsername};

        return snapshot.ref.parent!.parent!.update(updates);

    })
```